# Get all active store views domains

Tags: magento-1.8, multistore, collection

How could I get all active domains of current Magento Store? For active store view I can use:

```
$this->getRequest()->getHttpHost()
```

which gives me "www.example.com". But I wan't an array of all Magento store domains without leading http:// and / at the end.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
foreach ($stores as $store)
{
    echo parse_url($store->getBaseUrl(), PHP_URL_HOST);
}
```

Comment: @iztok I just saw you do not want to have http:// etc, so I updated my post.